# Why is it more common to use ceiling fans instead of air pumps?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, heat-transfer, hvac, building-design

As the title suggests, why not use high-powered air pumps instead of ceiling fans to inject hot air from the ceiling down to the cold, bottom floor?

I understand it may seem silly (especially since it may require a lot of energy), but wouldn't it work better than a series of fans in a large, tall warehouse for example?

Wouldn't the pressure differential in air pumps be sufficient to force the hot air at the ceiling down to the floor further and faster than ceiling fans?

Comment: Cost difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mainly cost difference.

And also, a fan is sufficient for the job. The problem being solved is thermal stratification. That's caused by a lack of vertical mixing; the warm air rises to the top, the cold air sinks.

Normally, there's quite a bit of movement in the first two metres or so from the ground - thermal stratification starts when the ceiling gets to around 3 metres or more.

Fans introduce enough vertical mixing, that when combined with general activities at ground-level, the thermal stratification gets sufficiently disrupted, for pretty low capital and operating costs, and with a device that's very easy to fit and to maintain, has a long life, doesn't have filters that need cleaning, and is generally quite quiet in operation.

Comment: Might add that there's no need for immediate homogeneity, so even if fans take an hour to reach optimum mixing, that's ok; and they can maintain the mix after that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just want to ask you one more question. What if a customer wants destratification as quickly as possible in a huge warehouse 5 meters tall, for example? Would pumps be better if cost wasn't an issue? If the customer wanted the warehouse to have a homogeneous temperature from the floor to the ceiling, wouldn't pumps do it quicker than fans?